# How to observe LiveData from Repository?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, android-livedata

I'd like to get a User from my Room database using the Repository, and then observing it in the OverviewFragment.

*What I tried:*

- using an Observer in the fragment, but I got a NullPointerException.
- using `@{overviewViewModel.user.email}` in fragment_overview.xml: the application runs but nothing is displayed.
- Unit Testing and Instrumented Testing with a FakeRepository. The tests pass and the data are displayed.

*What I use:*

- Android Studio (up to date)
- Kotlin
- MVVM architecture
- Repository pattern linked to a Room database
- Constructor dependency injection (for the viewmodels)
- [ServiceLocator](https://proandroiddev.com/why-service-locator-is-so-unpopular-bbe8678be72c) pattern for testing

*User Flow (Navigation)*

The User opens the app, fills a form and clicks the registration button in the RegistrationFragment, then navigates to the OverviewFragment, where his data (Email, Password) are displayed.

**RegistrationViewModel:**

```
class RegistrationViewModel(private val repository: IUserRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main +  viewModelJob)

    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()

    val user: LiveData<User>
        get() = _user

    val email = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val password = MutableLiveData<String>()

    [...]

    fun onRegister() {

        val userEmail = email.value.toString()
        val userPassword = password.value.toString()

        registerUser(User(userEmail, userPassword))
    }

    private fun registerUser(newUser: User) = uiScope.launch {
        repository.registerUser(newUser)
    }

    [...]
}
```

**OverviewViewModel**

```
class OverviewViewModel(val database: UserDatabaseDao,
                        private val userRepository: IUserRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()

    val user: LiveData<User>
        get() = _user

    init {
        getUser()
    }

    private fun getUser() {
        runBlocking {_user.value = userRepository.getUser().value }
    }
```

**OverviewFragment:**

```
class OverviewFragment : Fragment() {

[...]
        overviewViewModel.user.observe(this, Observer {
                binding.apply {
                    textview.text = overviewViewModel.user.value!!.email
                    textview2.text = overviewViewModel.user.value!!.password
                }
        })
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
class UserRepository(private val dataSource: UserDatabaseDao,
                     private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) :
    IUserRepository {

    override suspend fun registerUser(user: User) = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        dataSource.insert(user)
    }

    override suspend fun getUser(): LiveData<User?> = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        return@withContext dataSource.getUser()
    }

    override suspend fun getUser(email: String): LiveData<User?> = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        return@withContext dataSource.getUser(email)
    }
}
```

**DatabaseDao:**

```
@Dao
interface UserDatabaseDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * from user_table WHERE email = :key")
    fun getUser(key: String): LiveData<User?>

    @Query("SELECT * from user_table")
    fun getUser(): LiveData<User?>

    @Query("SELECT * from user_table")
    fun getAllUsers(): LiveData<List<User>>

}
```

Note: there's only one user in the database, the one that fills the form in the RegistrationFragment.

Comment: Can you cut this down to the minimum code that does not work as expected? Review the guidelines on how to create a good question, because that will help you get answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I cut some code down and improved formatting (following the guidelines). Hope that will help!

Comment: I don't see any reason why you need to make a function suspendable when its returning a `LiveData`. `dataSource.getUser()` is supposed to return a `LiveData` instance immediately.

Comment: I would start refactoring some stuff as avoiding to use `!!` and instead use `?.let{ }`
Probably the crash comes from that point and if nothing is displayed, that value potentially is null.  Do you have your project in a git repo? @MrWhoever